# Excel VBA Compare cell value to list and overwrite value in separate sheet

Tags: vba, excel

In a workbook I have, users either manually enter an account code or select one from a list and the account codes are placed in column C (C7:C446) in a sheet called "JE". The account codes look like this ####### - ### - ## - ######. In column D (D7:D446) in sheet "JE", there is a formula that captures the last 6 digits of the account code. In a sheet called "required_refs", there is a list of 6 digit codes in column A. If the value in the D column in sheet "JE" equals any of the values in column A of "required_refs" sheet, I would like the value in the D column cell to overwrite the cell value in cell D1 in a separate sheet called "references" (I know that may have been confusing, sorry)

**Example**: if the value of D25 matches any of the values listed in column A of sheet "required_refs", upon double clicking a red colored F25 cell, put the value of D25 (of sheet "JE"), and put it in cell D1 on sheet "references".

I've taken a crack at it as best I know how. I've placed this code in sheet JE:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim project As Range: Set project = Range("D7:D446")
    Dim param As Range:    Set param = Worksheets("references").Range("D1").Value


    For Each cell In project
        If project.Value = Worksheets("required_refs").Range("A:A").Value Then
        Call gotoRef_ 'macro that simply selects/navigates to the required_ref sheet
        project.Value = param
        End If

End Sub
```

Thanks so much in advance for any suggestions on how to complete this. I can elaborate on this further if needed.

Comment: I suggested an alternative method as an answer, but if you HAVE to use VBA, what's the problem you're having exactly? What happens when you run this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do what you want:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

  If Intersect(Target, Range("F7:F446")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

  Dim varReference As Variant

  varReference = Columns("D").Cells(Target.Row).Value2
  If Not IsError(Application.Match(varReference, Worksheets("required_refs").Columns("A"), 0)) Then
    Worksheets("references").Range("D1").Value = varReference
  End If

End Sub
```

**Important Points:**

Whenever working with event handlers, *always* limit the scope of the target range in the first line. Otherwise, it might not work correctly or it could slow done your spreadsheet.

Make sure your `JE` sheet column `D` values and `required_refs` sheet column `A` values are ***all*** either text or numbers. Otherwise the values won't be compared correctly.

Note the usage of `Application.Match()` instead of `WorksheetFunction.Match()` to access the worksheet function. This, coupled with the use of a Variant type variable, allows us to trap the error that occurs if the match fails.

Answer (score 0):

You can always do this on the sheet. Consider the MATCH function. See [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MATCH-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a) for how to use MATCH.

Or another great tool if you're searching for something in a table associated with a value in another column (not your case I don't think)--VLOOKUP formula. Place this formula in the D cell of the sheet you want to place the numbers in. VLOOKUP is in the following format:

```
=vlookup(lookup value,table_array,column index number, [range lookup])
```

1. The lookup value is the 6 digit code you're looking for (on the JE sheet)
2. The table_array is simply selecting the values you want to search for (required_refs sheet)
3. The column index number would be one, since the table only has 1 column. It's basically the column number of the value you're looking for.
4. And range lookup is for if you think there might be more than one place where it matches.

For your case I think it would look like this:

```
=vlookup('JE'!D1,'required_refs'!A1:A,1,FALSE)
```

Then just lock the values you want to keep and click and drag down.

Explanation for VLOOKUP [here](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/07/17/excel-vlookup-tutorial-beginner/)